# Update widthAnchor on Device orientation

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, nslayoutanchor

I have this constraint in my controller for a view like this:

```
someView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.width).isActive = true
```

Now I've added this constraint in `willLayoutSubviews` to update it on device rotation.

But it doesn't seem to update, even more like it adds another width constraint, which of course conflicts with the old width constraint.

Now I don't really know a proper solution to update this width constraint, but it seems to me like I need to remove the constraint first and then set it again.

Which if I test this like this:

```
someView.constraints.forEach {
    someView.removeContraint($0)
}
```

This works like expected, only it deletes of course some constraints I don't want to delete... so also not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sol1**

hook the width constraint as `IBOutlet` and change it's constant in code like this

```
self.widthCon.constant = //value
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

**Sol2**

delete the constraint with identifier

```
someView.constraints.forEach {
   if $0.identifier == "set_id" {
      someView.removeConstraint($0)
      someView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.width).isActive = true
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Solution 2 did the trick! (i'm not using storyboards or xibs so i don't use IBOutlets)

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternate Solution:

If you have a reference to the `superview` of `someView` then you can simply assign equal width constraints like so:

```
someView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.widthAnchor)
```

This way you can let the Autolayout engine update the width automatically when the device orientation changes.